# Could Solr only support update field by id?

Tags: solr

I have some documents, I want to update some fields by one field (indexed, but not id), it seems Solr could not support it, I know Solr can update by id. Anyone could give me answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no similar way to SQLs `UPDATE collection SET field = 'foo' WHERE field = 'bar';`, no. You'd have to implement this yourself by fetching the documents, changing the value and then reindexing the documents.

Comment: Depends on which language you're used to - you'll write some custom code using a Solr library that fetches the document, updates the field and resubmits it (or updates the single field - see Atomic Updates or inplace updates). You can use the `_version_` field to make sure you're not overwriting changes from other threads.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not supported. See Solr [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/updating-parts-of-documents.html) about updating parts of documents.